# Possible to have more than one app clip per app?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-appclips

Say I want to build an app clip for my curbside pickup feature.

Is it possible to have another app clip for an unrelated in-store experience?

I can build both targets and run them just fine in Xcode, but when it comes to publishing, is this a possibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have one App Clip target when you upload your binary to App Store Connect, however you can configure multiple App Clip Experiences within the one App Clip.

From the Apple documentation:

> Some apps provide multiple experiences and App Clips can be configured to support each of them in a special way. For example, a restaurant app may support multiple restaurants. App Clips make it possible to create a unique experience for each restaurant through a single App Clip.

In your example, you could instead create separate *schemes* for your curbside pickup feature and unrelated in-store experience, both targeting your single App Clip target. Each scheme can specify its own Environment Variable for `_XCAppClipURL` so that you can test different invocations of your App Clip.

Answer (score 3):

No. Only One App Clip per App.
You can use other experiences for that unrelated experience